# "Remote System Explorer Operation" causing freeze for couple of seconds

Tags: eclipse

I observe "Remote System Explorer Operation" in Progress view of Eclipse after each save of Java file (so it might be related to compiling?). It makes the Eclipse unusable for 1 to 10 seconds. In some projects (of about the same size) it's quicker, in some it's slower.

I have no idea which plugin might be the cause for it. I have `Build id: 20090920-1017`. I have quite a few [plugins installed](http://so.pastebin.com/f3120dfe2).

I have tried turning all the remote systems to `enabled=false` under Preferences | Remote Systems (whatever it means). I didn't help.

Any idea how to solve it?

EDIT:

1. It doesn't happen when `Project | Build automatically` is turned off. So it's some part of the building process.

Comment: I have this problem from yesterday (2013-10-09) when I accepted new updates for STS.

Comment: I have this problem and its the year 2016 -- 7 YEARS LATER

Comment: I have just installed Eclipse Mars 2 and the problem is still there.

Comment: incredible this problem still is in Neon.2

Comment: same problem with STS 3.8.4 now in 2017

Comment: uninstalling spring tools in oxygen worked for me

Comment: Still there in 2018 :)

Comment: I have this problem and its the year 2018 -- 9 YEARS LATER !!!

Comment: Oh. Let's have a yearly event for this.

Comment: Uninstalling eclipse and switching to IDEA did the trick for me.

Comment: Update... I've the same problem in 2019!!! 10 years later! A special party to this event ;(

Comment: It's 2021 and the problem is still there :-) Happy anniversary

Comment: 2022 says hello

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Click on the `Windows` > `Preferences` menu
2. Select `General` > `Workspace` > `Build Order` in the tree
3. Uncheck `Use default build order`
4. Select `RemoteSystemsTempFiles`
5. Click `Remove Project`
6. Click `Apply and Close`

Comment: Brilliant -- as the year is now 2016, this should be the newly accepted answer.  However, I do wonder what removing that from the build will break?!

Comment: What happens if you add new projects -- are they added automatically to that list? If not, this should not be the preferred way, since people will very probably forget to add the projects manually. What do you think?

Answer (score 182):

Here are the steps:

1. Click on the `Windows` > `Preferences` menu
2. Select `General` > `Startup and Shutdown` in the tree
3. Uncheck `RSE UI`
4. Select `Remote Systems` in the tree
5. Uncheck `Re-open Remote Systems view to previous state`
6. Restart Eclipse

Note: You must have Eclipse 4.3.1 (or newer) due to a bug on previous version

Comment: Accepting this answer since it seems to be a solution to current generation of the problem. (I haven't observed the bug and the fix in particular)

Comment: tried all that, what finally worked for me was the last part - updating to luna (4.4.0)

Comment: Every new version of the eclipse is worse than the previous one.
More RAM, faster disks but the Eclipse is getting worse and worse

Comment: Now it's 2018. This issue is still not resolved! This didn't work for me. Try Q9703's: delete `RemoteSystemsTempFiles` from Windows -> Preferences -> -> General -> Workspace -> Build Order

Comment: The combination between this answer and Q9703's one allows a really good improvement in Eclipse performance. RSE must be disabled and also the automatic builds of its own projects.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler. I have followed the above solutions, but it didn't work for me

Comment: It's 2021 and the problem is still in Neon. Happy anniversary

Answer (score 9):

*This was driving me crazy too.*

Thanks to this topic I got to understand it was the plugin `RSE`, but I could not uninstall the `Remote System Explorer` plugin tool either.
I had to remove all the plugins whose name started by org.eclipse.rse in `plugins/`, it's working now.

Comment: Thanks, I am on STS 3.9.3.RELEASE, this seems to solve my problem

Comment: This seems to solve the issue, but in debug STS remains very slow, with continuing freezes. I think "Remote System Explorer Operation" is not the only fault.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having this issue also.

I have found that the operation is part of the `Remote System Explorer` plugin which comes packaged with `SpringSource 3.3 (Kepler)`. Trying to figure out how to uninstall it now. Will post back here once I find it.

Information on how to install can be found here (step 3): http://www.patrickjwaters.com/blog/2011-07-24/how-setup-eclipse-php-pdt-remote-system-explorer-theme-manager-and-drupal-plugins/35

As for uninstall I'm still trying (the option to uninstall is greyed out for me in the installation details panel).

I've tried `Windows > Preferences > Remote Systems`, setting everything to false but the problem still occurred.

**Solution**
We've since moved to a Vanilla install of Eclipse Kepler and just added the plugins we require (excluding Remote System Explorer). This has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

**Close the Git-Staging View !**

I had the same Problem on my Eclipse 4.3 Kepler. 
After removing (closing)  the Git-Staging View the Problem was resolved !

Comment: Exactly what I was expecting, I imported a Git project and the issue started, thanks for confirming. Basically, close all tabs that synchronize or update information about "current file in context" helps.

Comment: What if I need the Git view? :)

Comment: Didn't help :-(

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced "Remote System Explorer Operation" tasks running on resource save.

Kepler + AspectJ + SpringSource
In my case, it was caused by invalid aspectj pointcut definitions. I had 30 pointcuts and 4 of them referenced a deleted class.
I have noticed blinking Spring AOP markers.

After I have fixed the pointcuts, the freezing stopped.

Comment: ya.. If there are any Aspect checks are blinking den, that will cause this issue. My issue( Same ) got resolved after fixing/delete that particular class.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have found a work-around for this issue...

1. If the window pops up, close it then click the Stop button at the bottom
2. Uncheck "Build Automatically" under Project
3. Project | Build Project
4. Check "Build Automatically"

Now, try what you were doing again.

Answer (score 1):

`Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Remote System Details (or maybe Remote Systems)`

This is with Eclipse 4.3 Kepler (2013/2014)

Find the all non-LOCAL items and Delete them.  I could not see any DISABLE function.

For me this seems to stop the extra 1 to 3 second delay (on Intel i7 box) when saving with editor and an auto-build completes.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/128402-sts-3-3-0-m2-and-remote-system-explorer-poor-performances  hints that STS 3.4M1+ might alleviate the problems, I have not yet tried this as I only run GA releases so will try when Kepler SR1 comes out in 7 days from now.

Answer (score 1):

For me at this time for Spring Tool Suite 3.9.4. Release disabling remote system via preferences menu fixed the issue. [Here](http://www.programmersstack.com/2016/02/eclipse-freeze-for-few-seconds-due-to.html) is the reference that helped me. but after a while, the problem is there again!

Answer (score 0):

Switched to eclipse photon one week, didn't see the annoying "remote system...." any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experienced multiple remote system explorer operations while compiling a C++ project in eclipse (I'm using Nsight bu nvidia - eclipse based platform). 
After i did all the suggested solutions here, I still had the problem.

**BUT**- when i changed the `-Wall` option to `-w` option for the gcc compiler the problem disappeared.

**GO TO** - Project Properties -> Build-> Settings -> Tool settings tab-> gcc compiler -> warnings -> uncheck `-Wall` and check `-w`

The same goes for G++ Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced "`Remote System Explorer Operation`" tasks running on resource save.

When using  `AspectJ` Around method In my case, it was caused by `Aspectj` around method Spring AOP markers creation.

Delete the `AspectJ` Markers from the `Eclipse Markers` console system hang issue will be solved automatically.

Answer (score -7):

The issue disappeared after some update of the Eclipse libraries (still using the same build). So I guess the solution is to perform an update.

Comment: This "solution" does not help the rest of us!

Comment: Same issue here. Solution don't really work. Shouldn't be marked as answer.

Comment: It did work for me three years ago. Now (2013) for some reason I see a lot of activity in the question, which probably might or might not be unrelated to the previous behavior. Anyway, I don't have a problem with selecting some other answer if it's proven to help people.