# Eclipse java build slower after moving project to GIT

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm new to GIT and recently moved over one of my eclipse java projects.

I noticed a significant delay in the auto build of my project after moving it to GIT. Seems to be some GIT update that happens on every save.
"Updating GIT status for repository GIT"

I'd appreciate any insights.
Eclipse version: Luna RC3 Release (4.4.0RC3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse: "re-indexing repository workspace" or "Computing Git status for repository workspace"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397074/eclipse-re-indexing-repository-workspace-or-computing-git-status-for-reposit)

Comment: Pls state your Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the culprit but almost every time in the last couple of Eclipse releases I have had issues with the Remote System Explorer which often for some reason gets called when you have source control plugins or aspectj on a project.

For a git project on Luna I turned it off by following:

["Remote System Explorer Operation" causing freeze for couple of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631817/annoying-remote-system-explorer-operation-causing-freeze-for-couple-of-seconds)

Yes the answer is for a different problem but again I have found the Remote System Explorer to be the culprit (or maybe indirectly I don't know for sure but I do know when I turn it off things get faster). There is also some [git specific answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23533805/318174) to that referenced SO question but I found I had to turn RSE completely off.