# How to avoid Remote System Explorer Operation on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I'm using Eclipse (tried with Luna,Mars,Oxygen) for Spring boot project. 
I have installed 2 plugins SpringBoot and TestNG on top of default configuration. 
I use EGIT for version control system.

My Eclipse is very slow, I have always the job "Remote System Explorer Operation". I disable it according to answers here : ["Remote System Explorer Operation" causing freeze for couple of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631817/remote-system-explorer-operation-causing-freeze-for-couple-of-seconds)

The problem persist.

How can I speed up my configuration ? Should I remove Spring Boot pluggin from Eclipse ?

Comment: This is an annoying issue which is also present in STS (Spring Tool Suite), anyone has found a working solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but I ran into the same kind of issue (but for me, I was not able to get back control on Eclipse)

I resolved it by deleting the "RemoteSystemsTempFiles" folder in my workspace

Hope it can help

Comment: Where is this directory?

Comment: I must admit I can't remember... A search in your workspace should help

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the "RemoteSystemsTempFiles" folder in

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USER\eclipse-workspace\RemoteSystemsTempFiles
```

This worked for me. Thanks to alban maillere.